# Layer Type Detection Bug in Altium Designer

Tags: altium, pcb-layers, gerber

When I open the "Layer Types Detection Template" by going to "Tables" -> "Layer Type Detection..." I see a list of "Layer Type" and next to that, the "Layer Type String Template". The strings that are used to try and detect the layers are incorrect.

Basically, what happens is this. If I install a fresh copy of Altium, and I try to make gerber files for a pcb, I can detect the layer types using that layer type detection template. The first time I do this, it will work fine. If I made a mistake or had to do another board, the file extensions in each row appear to shift up one row, and merge with the items in the row above. The attached picture shows how the bottom row shifted the file extensions up one row. If I used this tool again, the cells in the second column would shift up yet again.

You can look at the extensions and see how they are obviously not associated with the correct label in the left column.

I have had this bug in a version of Altium 18, 19 and 20. I must not be the only one having this issue and it is adding a TON of time to me getting boards created. Has anyone else had this issue and found a work around?

[image: Layer Type Detection Bug]

Comment: This is a very interesting bug for sure. If it's reproducable, I recommend posting it as a bug on the Altium board (https://bugcrunch.live.altium.com/#Bugs/New)

Comment: It is reported to Altium and they have reproduced it. They have been aware of it for over 8 months no with now fix in sight. I believe AD 17 doesn't have this bug, so my current work around is to do gerber and netlist generation in that version.

Comment: I'm suffering the same issue on 20.1.11. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuGuU.png) Did you find the solution? Thanks in advance.